# Why is nginx running with a new PID each time I list my processes

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, centos

Why is nginx restarting with a new PID each time I list processes?

And also, why is nginx running to begin with?

Refer to image below for output.

[Nginx Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfogU.png)

I don't know if this is useful but I am running a Centos web server with Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx is not running. You search the process table for `nginx` with `grep nginx`, but this causes the string `nginx` to appear in the process table, namely in the grep process. If you look careful, you can see that `grep nginx` is listed as the command for the process in question.

Naturally, this process is short lived and the next time you run the search, it will be a completely new process with a new PID.

Comment: Silly me, I was worried it was an exploit shell of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a second filter to your ps command :

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep nginx
```

You would then realize the absence of nginx process